# Playing chess until one party wins or ties 5 times

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Players $A$ and $B$ decide to play chess until one of them wins or ties $5$ times in a row.

Assume games are independent, where $A$ wins with probability $P(A) = 0.3$, $B$ wins with probability $P(B) = 0.25$, and they draw if $P(D) = 0.45$ on each game.

If the game ends in a draw another game will be played until they tie 5 times. Find the probability $A$ wins before $B$.

Comment: Are you asking the probability that A wins one game before B wins one?  The impact of stopping after five of the same result in a row is tiny because it is almost certain that A or B will win a game first.

Comment: Where did this problem come from?

Comment: my textbook, but no answer

Comment: HINT: separate the three options into "A wins on this game" and "A does not win on this game".

Answer (score 1):

The chance they tie the first five games in a row is $0.45^5$.  If they do, they quit and neither A nor B wins a game.  If they do not tie the first five, A will win the first decided game with probability $\frac {0.3}{0.3+0.25}=\frac 6{11}$.  The probability A wins without B having won (so it is clear that we accept cases where A wins and B never does) is $\frac 6{11}\left(1-0.45^5\right)$.  Similarly, the probability B wins without A having won is $\frac 5{11}\left(1-0.45^5\right)$

"Find the probability A wins before B" could also require that they both win at least one game but I don't read it that way.